# Drools in Spark - performance

Tags: apache-spark, drools

I have a batch job in Scala/Spark that dynamically creates Drools rules depending on some input and then evaluates the rules. I also have as input `RDD[T]` which corresponds to the facts to be inserted to the rule engine.

So far, I am inserting the facts one by one and then triggering all rules on this fact. I am doing this using [`rdd.aggregate`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#aggregate(U,%20scala.Function2,%20scala.Function2,%20scala.reflect.ClassTag)).

The seqOp operator is defined like this :

```scala
/**
 * @param broadcastRules the broadcasted KieBase object containing all rules
 * @param aggregator used to accumulate values when rule matches
 * @param item the fact to run Drools with
 * @tparam T the type of the given item
 * @return the updated aggregator
 */
def seqOp[T: ClassTag](broadcastRules: Broadcast[KieBase])(
  aggregator: MyAggregator,
  item: T) : MyAggregator = {
  val session = broadcastRules.value.newStatelessKieSession
  session.setGlobal("aggregator", aggregator)
  session.execute(CommandFactory.newInsert(item))
  aggregator
}
```

Here is an example of a generated rule:

```
dialect "mvel"
global batch.model.MyAggregator aggregator
rule "1"
 when condition
 then do something on the aggregator
end
```

For the same RDD, the batch took 20 minutes to evaluate 3K rules but 10 hours to evaluate 10K rules!

I am wondering if inserting fact by fact is the best approach. Is is better to insert all items of the RDD at once then fire all rules? It doesn't seem optimal to me as all facts will be in the working memory at the same time.

Do you see any issue with the code above?

Comment: Sounds like your job can leverage some change in the partitioning scheme. Are there rules that you can expect to be evaluated with run times in different orders of magnitude or are more or less all rules similar?

Comment: Rules are more or less similar. I put an example of a generated rule above

Comment: What does the Spark UI tells you about how the data is partitioned? Do you notice some skewing?

Comment: No the data is well partitioned between different executors

Comment: Do you notice unusual GC times?

Comment: No not really, GC time is more a less the same regardless of the duration of the task

Comment: can you give a reproducer of your project so that i can check where are you making mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured out the issue, it was more linked to the action done on the aggregator when a rule matches rather than the evaluation of the rules.